# kendo ui grid data not showing from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to show data into my kendo grid. I am using basic php mysql to return result from database. Here is my code for kendo javascript.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    // type: "json",
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: 'que.php',
                            ContentType: 'application/json',
                            type: 'GET',
                            dataType: 'json'
                        }
                    },
                    schema: {
                        data: 'rows'
                    }
                    // pageSize: 20
                },
                height: 550,
                groupable: true,
                sortable: true,
                pageable: {
                    refresh: true,
                    pageSizes: true,
                    buttonCount: 5
                },
                columns: [{
                    field: "student_name",
                    title: "NAME",
                    width: 240
                }, {
                    field: "nic",
                    title: "NIC"
                }, {
                    field: "father_name",
                    title: "Father Name"
                }, {
                    field: "dob",
                    title: "DOB",
                    width: 150
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And this is my php mysql file que.php. I return this file as json format.

```
    <?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include '../conn.php';
$query11 = "select student_name,nic,father_name,dob from student_info where program='diploma' and status='confirmed' order by batch,roll_no";
$run1 = mysql_query($query11);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($run1)){
    $rows[] = $r;
}
echo json_encode($rows, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

Kindly help me with this. I am new to kendo grid. Help will be really appreciated.

I am also sharing the image to help understand better.

[Here is what currently I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMFbD.jpg)

Kindly point me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Looks like your que.php page is not returning a well formed JSON object. Ensure that there are no unnecessary whitespaces at the beginning and at the end of the file. Also, try to access that page using your browser and inspect the result from the developer tools.

Comment: I noticed that there is `<br>` in the beginning of JSON object but dont know where it is coming from. I removed all whitespaces but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Just removed all white spaces and the `<br>` tag which was coming from the other page. And then remove rows from `data: 'rows'`. It worked.